# Toolbar color does not stays the same

Tags: android, android-fragments

I wanted to change `Toolbar` color programmatically, for this i am using this code:

```
((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.test)));
```

I have two fragments, A and B, Now suppose if switch to A, color changes to blue, now if switch to B, color changes to `test`, now again if switch to A and then to B, color stays blue!

For color changes in both the fragments i am using the above code. Above code trigger on `onCreateView`, which is the problem i think.

How can i make a listener for this, when fragment is on screen each time and color changes?

Comment: try change toolbar color in `onResume()`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.test)));
```

and

```
getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue)));
```

in the Activity not in fragments

Comment: But i want to change color according to fragment!

Comment: Oh, I thought you were using tabs. But you can still use the above code when changing the fragments